# Draw graphs in WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, xceed

I am new to C# and WPF, this is my first application.
I managed to display the content of a csv file in a window and I wish to draw charts of this data (column based on the other ...). My problem is that I can not install the Xceed Wpf Toolkit on my PC (for security reasons). I added the two dlls `Xceed.Wpf.DataGrid` and `Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit` as reference in my project and I don't know what to do to draw charts in my WPF application - as I mentioned I'm new to this technology.
Do you have please some explanations to guide me!

Comment: drawn sharts? That's an usual request on SO.

Comment: I have not found an answer to my question. I am new to this technology so do not be arrogant !!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Windows.Forms chart control. I've found this very straightforward in the past. Take a look at http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1006180/Using-Microsoft-Chart-in-WPF.

Comment: thank you for your reply

Comment: You're welcome. The only problem I recall I had with it (about 2 years ago now) was, if you're an MVVM purest you'll not like the codebehind you end up with.